# Generate n-gram based on value in other column for large set of data

Tags: python, pandas, performance, nltk, n-gram

My initial dataframe:

```
                           text  n_gram_len
0         This is the best text           2
1  This is some other best text           1
2   Well this is something else           3
```

Desired output:

```
                                              n_gram  
0             [This is, is the, the best, best text]  
1                [This, is, some, other, best, text]  
2  [Well this is, this is something, is something...
```

My code:

```
from nltk import ngrams
df['n_gram'] = df[['text', 'n_gram_len']].apply(lambda x: [' '.join(x) for x in ngrams(x.text.split(), x.n_gram_len)], axis=1)
```

The problem is that I have a dataframe with 100000 strings in it and the length with which to split. My code runs for 50 seconds. Is there any better way to do this or to improve the efficiency of current code.

As soon as I make n-grams I create more values. I use list as the data structure for storing n-grams. Is there any other way I could store so that further processing times reduce.